# Load QImage from byte array without knowing the format

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

[`QImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) has the following constructor:

```
QImage(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr);
```

However, I am trying to parse JPEG/PNG images that are already loaded as byte array. `QImage` also has other constructors, but those take already uncompressed byte array of ARGB values.

Is there a way to create `QImage` from unparsed byte data instead of file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can construct an empty `QImage` and then later use [`QImage::loadFromData(const QByteArray&)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData-1) without specifying a format. `QImage` will then try to read the image header to guess the file format.

```
QByteArray bytes; //contains image file contents
QImage img;
bool success = img.loadFromData(bytes);
```